# How to best get a repository from bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I was using git and bitbucket and then my computer crashed irrecoverably, and I am not working on a new computer, trying to get my old code base back.

I want to make sure I do everything cleanly and correctly so I wanted to ask here how to best get my code base back in order?

Should I just pull from bitbucket? Or should I create a repository locally first, and then pull into that repository?

Sorry if this is basic. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this in your terminal:

`git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/projectblah.git`.

Note that your exact username/project/url can be found on the right side of repo page on bitbucket.  This will clone the repo to your new computer and you treat the repo exactly the way you did on your old computer.

Comment: @john thank you. I actually get a git not found command so I have to get that figured out :)

Comment: That means git is not installed on your new system.  Here is a intro to installing git: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

Comment: @john thank you, going through that tutorial now. Turns out apt get or yum is also not installed :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked in all changes to bitbucket before crash, you could do a clone to get your code base.

```
git clone :repourl:
```

Clone is a prerequisite for any operation in Git.